# Schedule a local notification once the previous one has been sent

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

How can I know when a notification is sent even if the app isn't open so that i can cancel it and schedule a new one?

Current code:

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
notification.alertBody = athkar.randomItem()
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

But I don't know what to do after that, is it even possible?